# Добавление в массив Image из Resources

Tags: c#, winforms

Требуется добавить в массив Images картинки, которые предварительно добавил в Resources, их много, поэтому пытаюсь реализовать через цикл, но не понимаю как задать переменное имя в пути к ресурсу. Картинки в ресурсах имеют имя: _номерКартинки

задание одной картинки выглядит у меня так:

`images[0] = Properties.Resources._1;`

но хотелось бы реализовать что то вроде такого

```
Image[] images = new Image[207];

for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++) 
{
    images[i] = Properties.Resources.[i];
}
```

Comment: Это делается через `ResourceManager`, примерно так вы получаете все ресурсы: `var resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true).Cast<DictionaryEntry>();`, дальше уже делайте с этим что угодно, например, можете пройтись циклом и вытянуть нужные значения `foreach (var resource in resourceSet) { var key = resource.Key; var value = resource.Value; }` учтите, что там `object` везде, надо преобразовывать в нужный тип, где `Key` должен быть `string`, а `value` это массив байт (`byte[]`).

Comment: Аналогично кстати делается и получение значения, зная его имя. Вот допустим вы сохранили где-то имена, и в какой-то момент надо уже получить сам ресурс, вы пишете `var value = resourceSet.Get...("имяРесурса");`, где `...` - это тип конкретного ресурса, например `.GetString("СуперСтрока")` найдет ресурс с именем "СуперСтрока" и скастует его в `string`, ну а если там картинка, то это массив байт, в таком случае вызываем `.GetObject("Фотка1")`, получим `object`, который уже можно будет преобразовать в нужный тип самостоятельно.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое!